# Sorting array of objects in EJS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, ejs

I am finding trouble in sorting an array of objects in EJS (sent from the server in `Node.js`). The array of objects consists of multiple lessons with their details. Below is the `joinLecture.js` file in which the array of objects is being sent to the EJS. `res.render("lectureSearch", {searchData: mappedResults});`. This works completely fine and can be displayed in EJS (without the sorting functionality). Below is the EJS that is giving me trouble in sorting the array of objects.

```html
<h2>Current Lectures</h2>
        <table id="lecturesTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Teacher</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>Additional Notes</th>                               
                </tr>
            <thead>
            <tbody id="lecturesTableData">
                <% if(data.length){ %>
                    <% function loadTableData(data){ %>
                       <% for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%=data[i].school%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].location%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].class%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].subject%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].teacher_name%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].date%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].start_time%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].end_time%></td>
                                <td><%=data[i].additional_notes%></td>
                            </tr>
                        <% } %>
                    <% } %>
                <% }else{ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>No Lessons</td>
                    </tr>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button onclick="sortSchoolAscending()">School Ascending</button>
        <button onclick="sortSchoolDescending()">School Descending</button>
        <button onclick="sortLocationAscending()">Location Ascending</button>
        <button onclick="sortLocationDescending()">Location Descending</button>
</body>
<script> 
    function sortSchoolAscending(){
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(b.school) - parseFloat(a.school);
        });
        loadTableData(data);
    }

    function sortSchoolDescending(){
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.school) - parseFloat(b.school);
        });
        loadTableData(data);
    }

    function sortLocationAscending(){
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(b.school) - parseFloat(a.school);
        });
        loadTableData(data);
    }

    function sortLocationDescending(){
        data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.school) - parseFloat(b.school);
        });
        loadTableData(data);
    }
</script>
```

The lessons table works well without the `loadTableData` EJS function, but has no sorting. Below is the error that I am receiving.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
> at sortSchoolAscending
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

I have been trying to solve this issue for quite some time so your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't defined data anywhere, globally or inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, without the function 'loadTableData' in the EJS, the data is displayed in the table and the data.length is received by the if statement and for loop. What will I have to do to make the function receive the data too so the sorting works please?

Comment: Pass 'data' as a parameter to the function.

Comment: I just used data as a parameter and receiver error: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at sortSchoolAscending
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: The first comment above is relevant. Please show where you have defined `data`. I know you say it works without the function, but please understand that the question is still pertinent: where is `data` defined`?

Comment: Also, why do you use `parseFloat`? Are schools and locations all numbers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed the sorting function to that mentioned in another answer to this question. Data was passed down from the server in Node.js and was not defined in the ejs file. I am confused as the data array worked in displaying the table but not in the script tag. How will I be able to define it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work with the function. Remove it again, so you just have:

```js
    <tbody id="lecturesTableData"> 
        <% if(data.length){ %>
           <% for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=data[i].school%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].location%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].class%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].subject%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].teacher_name%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].date%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].start_time%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].end_time%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].additional_notes%></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        <% }else{ %>
            <tr>
                <td>No Lessons</td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
```

This will populate the table at page load. Sorting can then be based on the table rows themselves.

Your `script` tag could sort the table *rows* as follows:

```js
const tbody = document.getElementById("lecturesTableData");

// Helper function for sorting on a given column, with a given comparator
function tableSort(colNum, cmp) {
  let rows = [...tbody.rows];
  rows.sort((a, b) => cmp(a.cells[colNum].textContent, b.cells[colNum].textContent))
    .map(row => tbody.appendChild(row));
}

function sortSchoolAscending() {
  tableSort(0, (a, b) => a - b); // assuming that school column has number representations
}

function sortSchoolDescending() {
  tableSort(0, (a, b) => b - a); // assuming that school column has number representations
}

function sortLocationAscending() {
  tableSort(1, (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); // assuming that location column has strings
}

function sortLocationDescending() {
  tableSort(1, (a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)); // assuming that location column has strings
}
```

```css
td, th { border: 1px solid }
th { background: lightgray }
table { border-collapse: collapse }
button { margin: 5px }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="lecturesTableData">
    <tr>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Paris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>Brussels</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="sortSchoolAscending()">School Ascending</button>
<button onclick="sortSchoolDescending()">School Descending</button>
<button onclick="sortLocationAscending()">Location Ascending</button>
<button onclick="sortLocationDescending()">Location Descending</button>
```

I assumed here that the school column has number representations, and the location column has strings that are not number representations. This way you can see how the call to `tableSort` differs, and adapt as needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried using this code and it gave me an error of Uncaught ReferenceError: tbody is not defined
    at tableSort. I then used document.getElementByID for the tbody and another error was displayed, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null
    at tableSort

Comment: I then tried replacing 'rows' with the data array, which lead to Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
    at tableSort

Comment: Yes, indeed you need to have `tbody` equal to your `tbody` element. So make sure that you use the correct syntax for that assignment. I have added it at the top of the script in my answer.

Comment: Also make sure the `script` element is below the HTML content (like you have it in  the question), just before the closing `</body>` tag. If it still doesn't work, please post a snippet (maybe a link to jsfiddle) so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: Any news? I added a runnable snippet to my answer with some sample data in the table (so excluding the EJS part).

Comment: Works perfectly with EJS too, thanks a lot for patience! Highly appreciated :)